# embed all required DLLs in one dll

Tags: c++, dll, activex, visual-studio-6

I am creating ActiveX control with visual c++ 6.

my control uses some DLLs, and I want to embed all those DLLs in the output DLL

how can I do That?

Comment: It's 2017, why are you still using that? It predates Windows 2000 and Windows ME, and targeted Window 98/NT4. What OS are you planning to deploy on?!

Comment: I am editing a very old project was created by that version of visual studio.

Comment: I want to deploy on windows xp and higher

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the security concerns in a runtime that old, on top of that the code the compiler generates will be insanely fat and slow.

This existing Stack Overflow Answer answers your question as well as I could - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3595965/6476520