# Cmake: How to statically link packages to shared library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to create a `.dll` library with all its dependencies packed inside the `.dll`.

However, there seems to be no easy way to achieve that with Cmake. My setup:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Main VERSION 0.1.0)

add_library(Main SHARED Main.cpp)

find_package(libzippp REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(Main PRIVATE libzippp::libzippp)
```

This will produce both `Main.dll` but also `libzippp.dll`.

I would like to have `libzippp.dll` packed (statically linked) into `Main.dll`.

Comment: "I would like to have `libzippp.dll` packed (statically linked) into `Main.dll`." - You cannot. It is not restriction of CMake itself, but it is a restriction of `.dll` format which doesn't support merging such files into the one of the same format. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595937/combine-multiple-dlls-into-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't pack one DLL into another. You have to make `libzippp` a static library in the first place. To do this, build `libzippp` with `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` set to `NO` at the CMake command line. Then `libzippp::libzippp` will be a static library when you go to `find_package` it.

This is easy enough to show steps for:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:ctabin/libzippp.git
$ cmake -S libzippp -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/local -DLIBZIPPP_BUILD_TESTS=NO
$ cmake --build build --target install
$ tree local
local/
├── include
│   └── libzippp
│       └── libzippp.h
├── lib
│   └── libzippp_static.a
└── share
    └── libzippp
        ├── FindLIBZIP.cmake
        ├── libzipppConfig.cmake
        ├── libzipppConfigVersion.cmake
        ├── libzipppTargets.cmake
        └── libzipppTargets-release.cmake
```

Comment: I am using `vcpkg.json` to manage the packages. Is there a way to make it download / build static packages on its own?

Comment: @FordO. Use a `static` target triple like `x64-windows-static`. If you're using the toolchain file in manifest mode, it should be enough to set `-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows-static` at the CMake command line.

Comment: Nice. I have added `set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET x86-windows-static)` at the top of my cmake.